# dojo named class - when to use them and how to create them?

Tags: dojo

I'm reading through the dojo classy [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/declare/), and there is an example of creating a named class:

```
// Create a new class named "mynamespace.MyClass"
declare("mynamespace.MyClass", null, {

    // Custom properties and methods here

});
```

Question: **When should I use named classes and when should I use anonymous classes?**

> *"A class named mynamespace.MyClass is now globally available within the application"*

Question: **How do I create an instance of my class within the application?**

> *"Named classes should only be created if they will be used with the
>   Dojo parser. All other classes should omit the className parameter."*

Question: **What does this mean?**

Comment: Interesting. I remember to have read something that you sould not use named classes any more when using the AMD loader. Those classnames esp. have been used by the dojo parser to identify widgets, but since dojo 1.8 you also can use the module name "my/form/InputWidget" as the data-dojo-type directly. So I don't see any use for the named classes any more.

Answer (score 0):

When should I use named classes and when should I use anonymous classes?

Prior to Dojo 1.8, you need to use the first argment to provide a class name which was used both to define the class in a namespace as well as by the dojo parser (for declarative markup) in the dojoType attributes.

How do I create an instance of my class within the application?

```
// First make sure to import/alias the declare module in your application module that will be declaring the new class:
//    define([dojo/_base/declare],function(declare){}){

// From 1.8+, you don't need the class name parameter.  
// Supplying the name provides no additional value.
declare(null, {
    // Custom properties and methods here
});
```

The official reference guide page for dojo declare with more info is found here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare

What does this mean?
It's no longer relevant for the parser.  It used to be that the class name argument was used by the dojo parser when parsing html fragments to match the data-dojo-type="" to these class names.  Now you can just put the AMD module identifier eg. "dijit/Button" of the module which returns your widget's constructor function and the parser can automatically load and instantiate widgets without using the class name.